# Return multiple values (OUTPUT) stored procedure to dataset or datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, output

Here is my question: I am working with a stored procedure that returns multiple results, but what I need to know, how can I pass (retrieve) the "output" values of the stored procedure to a dataset or datable?

The resulset that returns from the stored procedure I capture them well with a `SqlDataAdapter` and the method `Fill`, that's resolved, but what I need is the output values in a dataset or datatable, because those values will contain a set of output data.

I have researched but I can not find anything to get the outputs in a dataset or datable.

There are many issues about multiple results but that is resolved I do not need that part because I have it resolved, only that those output can be passed to dataset or datatable.

Beg my pardon for grammar in English, as I am using translator, thank you.

Attaching the values to embed in a dataset after they are returned by the stored procedure.

C# 2010 and SQL Server 2014

Thank you, but you have not understood my question I will leave my code so you can understand.

As you can see, I have everything working, the stored procedure, returns 2 tables and additionally a set of output data, the two resulting tables I get with the `SqlDataAdapter` and the `Fill` method, and the output values are allocated individually, but I do not want it to be individual, I need ALL the output values in a dataset or datatable, like the other results

```
// Function
private void procedure(decimal id, string date)
{
    bool done = false;

    SqlTransaction Transaction = null;

    int value_return = 0;

    try
    {
        // Function
        open_conexion();

        // Transaction
        Transaccion = conexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("NameStoreProcedure", conexion, Transaction);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Clear();

        // Multiple resulsets
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);

        // Output values
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value3", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value4", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value5", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value6", SqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value7", SqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value8", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Value9", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        // Return Value
        command.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        string output_values = string.Empty;

        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        // 2nd Resulset
        dataadapter.Fill(dataset, "Table1, Table2");

        // These values, instead of having them in a string variable, I need them in a //dataset or datatable
        // Values Output
        output_values = "Value1: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value1"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value2: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value2"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value3: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value3"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value4: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value4"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value5: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value5"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value6: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value6"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value7: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value7"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value8: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value8"].Value) + " \n" +
                        "Value9: " + Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Value9"].Value);

        value_return = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@return_value"].Value);

        if (value_return == 0)
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + exception.Message, "ERROR ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (done)
        {
            Transaction.Commit();
            close_conexion();
        }
        else
        {
            Transaction.Rollback();
            close_conexion();
        }
    }
}
```

[IMAGE result of stored procedure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vumsG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve output parameters AFTER finisted SQL `DataReader` stream. That means you couldn't get the output parameters until you read all the rows from the DataReader. So, if you want to set output values to all rows (I don't recommend it, It would causes redundant data), you can do it like this;

```
        foreach (DataTable datasetTable in dataset.Tables)
        {
            datasetTable.Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(string));
            datasetTable.Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(string));
            datasetTable.Columns.Add("Value3", typeof(string));
            datasetTable.Columns.Add("Value4", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataRow datasetTableRow in datasetTable.Rows)
            {
                datasetTableRow["Value1"] = command.Parameters["@Value1"].Value;
                datasetTableRow["Value2"] = command.Parameters["@Value2"].Value;
                datasetTableRow["Value3"] = command.Parameters["@Value3"].Value;
                datasetTableRow["Value4"] = command.Parameters["@Value4"].Value;
            }
        }
```

Or you can create another table for outputvalues like this;

```
    dataset.Tables.Add("OutputResults");
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("Value3", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("Value4", typeof(string));
    var outputRow = dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].NewRow();
    outputRow["Value1"] = command.Parameters["@Value1"].Value;
    outputRow["Value2"] = command.Parameters["@Value2"].Value;
    outputRow["Value3"] = command.Parameters["@Value3"].Value;
    outputRow["Value4"] = command.Parameters["@Value4"].Value;
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Rows.Add(outputRow);
```

Another option is you can add the rows as key-value pair for per output values in created table like this;

```
    dataset.Tables.Add("OutputResults");
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("OutputName", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Columns.Add("OutputValue", typeof(string));

    var value1Row = dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].NewRow();
    value1Row["OutputName"] = "Value1";
    value1Row["OutputValue"] = command.Parameters["@Value1"].Value;

    var value2Row = dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].NewRow();
    value2Row["OutputName"] = "Value2";
    value2Row["OutputValue"] = command.Parameters["@Value2"].Value;

    var value3Row = dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].NewRow();
    value3Row["OutputName"] = "Value3";
    value3Row["OutputValue"] = command.Parameters["@Value3"].Value;

    var value4Row = dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].NewRow();
    value4Row["OutputName"] = "Value4";
    value4Row["OutputValue"] = command.Parameters["@Value4"].Value;

    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Rows.Add(value1Row);
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Rows.Add(value2Row);
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Rows.Add(value3Row);
    dataset.Tables["OutputResults"].Rows.Add(value4Row);
```

Comment: Thanks

Please review my question again, edit it so you can understand better, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you,
Do not use DataReader, use DataAdapter
storage procedure only returns 2 tables, which I have already opted for with the fill.

The output values will not be repeated (it is also a resulting table), BUT THE DATATASET only contains the two resulting tables, the output values are not included in that dataset, what I want is to include the output values in that same dataset as another table. The solution that you propose to me is directly if the dataset already has the output data. The output data is not included in this dataset. I want to include them once I see how to handle them.

Comment: Please look at the image that I have uploaded:

IMAGE Result of store Procedure Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vumsG.png

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second solution that you propose, it works for me. Thanks for your reply friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should provide a dataset to be filled by your dataadapter just like this :

```
DataTable myTable= new DataTable();


using (var con = new SqlConnection(AConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STORED_PROCEDURE", con)) 
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //Data adapter(da) fills the data retuned from stored procedure 
   //into myTable
    da.Fill(myTable);
}
```

this will return you the datatable you're after....

But with your additionnal edit code, I rhink that you want to return different resultset at the same time. If so you could consider using [MARS (Multiple active Result Set)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/manipulating-data)

I have updated my response : you could retrieve all resultsets as 3 dataTables in your existing dataset, then create another dataset and copy to it your last dataTable, or simply copy it...

Comment: Thanks

Please review my question again, edit it so you can understand better, Thank you.

Comment: Please look at the image that I have uploaded:

IMAGE Result of store Procedure Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vumsG.png

Comment: Ok thank you for providing info. Here the simple way to do that : retrieve all the 3 datatables in one go : dataadapter.Fill(dataset, "Table1, Table2","Table3");  and then create another dataset to copy the table3 in it via : AnotherDataset.Tables.Add( dataset.Tables["Table3"].Copy() );

Comment: Dypso, I tried this way but it does not work like that, the following exception occurs: Can not find table 3.